# Unable to access images folder present in another machine from Android app through Wifi

Tags: c#, android, image, wcf, wifi

I got stuck in my application with images part, when trying to access from Android app, where the images are located in remote machine and need to access through WiFi connection.

Here is the complete scenario of my application.

I have an windows application which will save images to the folder where application got installed. dotNet application saves and retrieves images without any issues.

But I have android application which consumes wcf service (both windows and wcf). Consuming service part is also working fine in android and windows application.

Problem arises with images. Actually in database I am saving image location rather than saving the image as a byte array. But android app unable to access the location of the images folder. Because the location where application is installed was unable to access through LAN or Wifi using the URL like **"IP Address/AppInstalFolde/LocalImages/ABC.jpeg."**

I tried to allow access to that machine by sharing that folder across LAN, but still I could not able to access the images from Android app

I have tried with all possible ways and now in the situation that I cannot make a whole application change by allowing to convert an image to byte array in the database.

I am looking for alternative way to solve this problem.

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host a website, contains all the images in the IIS (The same as hosting WCF services). And then the Android App will connect to the website to get the images.

Comment: What about dotNet app? Can it consume the same images hosted in IIS. Like I will save the URL in my database and will access the image with the url. For supporse, if I hosted in IIS the URL will be like localhost/.... some thing similar. Am I right @conanaka99. Please provide me a link on the same

Comment: When the images is hosted, they still exist in a folder on your computer. You only need to change the path to the hosted folder.

Comment: You mean to say like - change the path of virtual directory from IIS to point to the physical location. Then in that case, I need to save the ImageURL like localhost/AppFolderName/Images/ABC.jpg (say suppose ABC.jpg is the image present in Images folder which is present in the application installed location). Am I on the right track? Please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: @Ganesh: Yes, just do it as you think. If you met any problems, post it here and I'll help you resolve it.

Comment: I got the working solution from the above answer and this is what I did, I have created a virtual directory in IIS and pointed to my images folder (images folder under where the application has installed) and then accessed with the url like localhost(machine ip address)/VirtualDirectoryName/ImageName.Ext. It works.